# Reading from a file and outputting its contents in Assembly

Tags: assembly, file-io, x86, x86-16, tasm

I have here a code snippet that prints a welcome message (menu) using video mode `10h`. When <kbd>4</kbd> is pressed, it should read from a file and display its contents on the screen. However, it displays garbage values and I have to open DOSBox and mount again.

```
.model small 
.stack 1024 
.data 

MENU        DB 10,""
            DB 10,"          Welcome       "    ;24
            DB 10,""
            DB 10,"1 Novice"                ;3, 9
            DB 10,"2 Boss"                  ;3, 6
            DB 10,"3 Superb"                ;3, 11
            DB 10,"4 Scores"    
            DB 10,""
            DB 10,"Choice: ","$"                ;8
            
ROW1 DB 5   
ROW2 DB 10
COL DB 25       

Choice DB ?

; OTHER DECLARATIONS FOR COLORING I WON'T SHOW FOR SIMPLICITY

FileName DB "file.txt",0,8 ; name of file to open 
Handle   DW ?   ; to store file handle 

BufferSeg   dw  0

ErrMsgOpen  db  "Error opening `"
FileLength dw 0

nextLine    db  13,10

.code 

DisplayFile PROC NEAR
    
    ;escape to video mode
    mov ax,0A000h
    mov es,ax
    xor di,di
    xor ax,ax
    mov cx,32000d
    cld
    rep stosw
    
    mov     ax,cs
    mov     ds,ax
    mov     bx,ss
    add     bx,200h/10h     ;get past the end of the file
    mov     [BufferSeg],bx  ;store the buffer segment
        
    ;call   WriteFile 
    push    ds

    mov     ax,cs
    mov     ds,ax
    mov     ax,3d00h    ;open file (ah=3dh)
    mov     dx,offset FileName
    int     21h
    mov     bx,ax       ;move the file handle into bx

    mov     ds,[BufferSeg]
    mov     dx,0            ;load to [BufferSeg]:0000
    mov     ah,3fh
    mov     cx,0FFFFh       ;try to read an entire segments worth
    int     21h

    mov     [cs:FileLength],ax

    mov     ah,3eh
    int     21h             ;close the file

    cld
    mov     si,0
    mov     cx,[cs:FileLength]
    
    PrintLoop:
        mov     ah,2
        lodsb
        mov     dl,al
        int     21h         ;print a character
    
        dec     cx
        jne     PrintLoop
        
        pop     ds
        ret

    OpenError:
        mov     ah,9
        mov     dx,offset ErrMsgOpen
        int     21h
    
        pop     ds
        ret
DisplayFile ENDP 

.STARTUP
    mov     ax, @data 
    mov     ds, ax 
        
    @welcome:
        mov ax, 3
        int 10h
        
        MOV AX, 3       ; 80x25 color
        INT 10H         ; video BIOS call   
        MOV AH, 2       ; set cursor position
        MOV BH, 0       ; display page number
        MOV DH, ROW1        ; row number
        MOV DL, COL     ; column number
        INT 10H         ; video BIOS call
        LEA BP, ATT_BRICK       ; point to first attribute array 
        CALL FAR PTR STICK   ; display first line of video text
        
        
        ;scanf user's choice
        mov ah, 01h
        int 21h
        sub al, '0'
        mov Choice, al
        
        ; OTHER CODES
        
        cmp al, 4
        je @scores
        
    @score:
        call    DisplayFile
    
    @quit: 
        mov     ax, 4c00h       ;call dos to exit 
        int     21h 
        
.EXIT
END
```

Basically it is a game that saves the results in a file. I can write to the file properly but when I'm trying to read from it, it does not output to the screen.

**EDIT**

This is the same as what `DisplayScore proc near` does but in a separate .ASM file. It's there just to test if reading from a file works and it does.

```
 .MODEL SMALL
    .STACK 200h
    .CODE
    Ideal

;===- Data -===

BufferSeg   dw  0

ErrMsgOpen  db  "Error opening `"
FileName    db  "file.txt",0,8,"'$"     ;8 is a delete character

                                        ;0 is required for filename 
                                        ;(displays a space)
FileLength dw 0

buffer db "hehe$"
;===- Subroutines -===

PROC DisplayFile NEAR
    push    ds

    mov     ax,cs
    mov     ds,ax
    mov     ax,3d00h    ;open file (ah=3dh)
    mov     dx,offset FileName
    int     21h
    jc      OpenError
    mov     bx,ax       ;move the file handle into bx

    mov     ds,[BufferSeg]
    mov     dx,0            ;load to [BufferSeg]:0000
    mov     ah,3fh
    mov     cx,0FFFFh       ;try to read an entire segments worth
    int     21h

    mov     [cs:FileLength],ax

    mov     ah,3eh
    int     21h             ;close the file

    cld
    mov     si,0
    mov     cx,[cs:FileLength]
PrintLoop:
    mov     ah,2
    lodsb
    mov     dl,al
    int     21h         ;print a character

    dec     cx
    jne     PrintLoop
    
    pop     ds
    ret

OpenError:
    mov     ah,9
    mov     dx,offset ErrMsgOpen
    int     21h

    pop     ds
    ret
ENDP DisplayFile

;===- Main Program -===

START:
    mov     ax,cs
    mov     ds,ax
    mov     bx,ss
    add     bx,200h/10h     ;get past the end of the file
    mov     [BufferSeg],bx  ;store the buffer segment
    
    ;call   WriteFile
    call    DisplayFile

    mov     ax,4c00h
    int     21h
END START
```

Comment: Are you positive that `BufferSeg` is valid? Have you tried allocating memory using `int 21h` / `ah=48h` instead?

Comment: I tried separating the `DisplayScore proc near` in a separate file and it works, ie, it reads from the file and displays the contents in the screen. But when I incorporated it into the video mode, garbage value occurs. Please see edit to see the separate asm file though it's just the same as DisplayScore.

Comment: Does the original code even compile? You've got a `je @scores`, which I assume to be a jump to the very next line. But the label there is `@score` (no `s`).

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot to edit it in here. But yes, the original code compiles. :) I didn't just include the other parts because there are more than 1000 lines.

Answer (score 1):

If we start our application, then we become all of the free ram from DOS, so we can not know how many ram we actualy can use and which segment addresses are saved for DOS and TSR-Drivers. So we have to give back to DOS all that ram that we not yet needed in this moment, before we can request an new appointed amoung of ram from DOS beginning with a segmentaddress that continuously have free ram that is guarants not used form DOS or drivers.

```
          call SETFREE               ; calculate the amoung of ram that we need
                                     ; for running our application and giviving
                                     ; back the rest of ram to DOS

          mov      bx, 2000h         ; request/reserv 128 KB ram from DOS
          call GETSPACE
          jc  NOSPACE                ; Error!
          mov      [NEWSEG], ax      ; save segment address


;------------------------------------
SETFREE:  mov      bx, ss            ; First we subtract both segmentaddresses
          mov      ax, es            ; for to become the amoung of paragraphs
          sub      bx, ax            ; from the PSP to the beginning of the stack.
          mov      ax, sp            ; Because our stackpointer beginn at the end
          add      ax, 0Fh           ; of the stacksegment, we can use the stackpointer
          shr      ax, 4             ; for the length of the stack.
          add      bx, ax
          mov      ah, 4Ah           ; Set new size
          int    21h
          ret
;------------------------------------
GETSPACE: mov      ah, 48h           ; BX = number/16
          int    21h
          ret
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...in a separate asm file (just to test if reading from a file works and it is).

The *DisplayFile* proc works fine when operating from a separate program because of these two reasons:

- All the data items are placed in de `.CODE` section and setting the `DS` segment register is done alright with next code:

  ```
  mov     ax,cs
  mov     ds,ax
  ```
- The calculation of *BufferSeg* is correct because it matches the `.STACK 200h` setting:

  ```
  mov     bx,ss
  add     bx,200h/10h     ;get past the end of the file
  mov     [BufferSeg],bx
  ```

### Why then does it fail in the bigger program?

#### Errors

- The program uses a separate `.DATA` section for which your `.STARTUP` code initializes `DS` with `mov ax, @data` `mov ds, ax`. The copying of `CS` into `DS` that is still present in the *DisplayFile* proc, can no longer work!
- Also the program now uses a bigger stack (`.STACK 1024`), but you're still calculating *BufferSeg* as if the stacksize was 512. This means that loading the file will overwrite the stack and probably crash the program!

#### Advice

- In the `.STARTUP` code you setup the 80x25 16-color text video mode (twice!), but in the *DisplayFile* proc there's a sequence of instructions that is typical for clearing the 320x200 256-color graphics screen. This is confusing at best. But because you said that this is a game, video mode 13h is reasonable. Nonetheless, I would advice to delegate this clearing to a separate proc.
- Also, I see no reason to calculate the *BufferSeg* variable within the *Displayfile* proc. Its value is based upon the location of your stack and that will almost certainly remain invariant during program execution.
- Storing the file length to a memory variable not only is a wasteful operation, but it also complicates working with the `DS` segment register.
- Instead of trying to read "an entire segments worth", try to read a 'reasonable' number of bytes. I bet you the score will never require that many bytes... You could even decide to work with a fixed number of digits, which is not uncommon for a game.
- Once we accept that the score is a limited resource, we could choose to use a simple general purpose buffer defined in the `.DATA` section (`Buffer db 512 dup (0)`). We wouln't have to deal with changing `DS` anymore.

```
ClearScreen PROC NEAR
    push es
    mov  ax, 0A000h
    mov  es, ax
    xor  di, di
    mov  cx, 32000
    xor  ax, ax
    rep stosw
    pop  es
    ret
ClarScreen ENDP

DisplayFile PROC NEAR
    push ds
    call ClearScreen

    mov  ax, 3D00h         ; DOS.OpenFile for reading
    mov  dx, OFFSET FileName
    int  21h               ; -> AX CF
    jc   FileError
    mov  bx, ax            ; Handle

    mov  ds, [BufferSeg]
    xor  dx, dx            ; Load to [BufferSeg]:0000
    mov  cx, 512           ; Try to read a 'reasonable' number of bytes
    mov  ah, 3Fh           ; DOS.ReadFile
    int  21h               ; -> AX CF
    jc   FileError
    mov  cx, ax            ; Bytes read

    mov  ah, 3Eh           ; DOS.CloseFile
    int  21h               ; -> AX CF
    jc   FileError

    jcxz FileWasEmpty
    xor  si, si
  PrintLoop:
    lodsb
    mov  dl, al
    mov  ah, 02h           ; DOS.PrintCharacter
    int  21h      
    dec  cx
    jnz  PrintLoop

  FileWasEmpty
    pop  ds
    ret

  FileError:
    pop  ds                ; Restore DS first!
    mov  dx, OFFSET ErrMsgOpen
    mov  ah, 09h           ; DOS.PrintString
    int  21h
    ret
DisplayFile ENDP 

.STARTUP
    cld
    mov  ax, @data 
    mov  ds, ax 

    mov  ax, ss
    add  ax, 1024/16       ; Available memory (*)
    mov  [BufferSeg], ax

    ...

    call DisplayFile

    ...

    mov  ax, 4C00h         ; DOS.Terminate
    int  21h
```

(*) The [answer by Dirk Wolfgang Glomp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15765302/reading-from-a-file-and-outputting-its-contents-in-assembly/16331139#16331139) shows the secure way of doing this.